# How to read document from another repository in docusaurus

Tags: github, documentation, documentation-generation, docusaurus

I have created a Docusaurus app on a Github repository and I want to add some external sources to it. Those sources are one or more Github repositories from the same organisation.

There is any way to do that?

All the deployment process use Jenkins pipeline on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If this documentation is already deployed you can use this plugin:

https://github.com/rdilweb/docusaurus-plugin-remote-content/

But the problem is if this resources are not deployed on a web server yet because it not support a Git url as remote source, [see](https://github.com/rdilweb/docusaurus-plugin-remote-content/issues/50).

So another option could be to pull the content before each `docusaurus build|start`.

Comment: Does someone has an example of pulling content from different repository? How would be the process?

Comment: You can do it on two ways: first one, adding a pre build script on the package.json, the other, using github actions. I have not a working example right now